# Question concerning tenses

Tags: tenses, sentence, present-perfect, present-tense, simple-past

*Lauren has coaxed her brother many times to go cinema with her but he never listens*

*Lauren has coaxed her brother many times to go cinema with her but he never listened*

Which sentence is correct?

Lauren has tried several times to take her brother to a cinema (action beginning at some time in the past and continuing up to the present moment) but her brother has a habit of not listening to her persuasion to go cinema with her. This is the idea that I want to convey in my sentence but I'm confused if I should use the simple present or simple past after the conjunction *BUT* in my sentence. Please help!

Comment: There's a third possibility: *he has never listened*.

Comment: Aside: IMO you would use the word [**coax**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/coax) when you *successfully* persuade someone, so it is out of place here.

Comment: Lauren often tries to take her brother along to the cinema but he will never go.

Comment: Thanks Vane and Thanks Peter for taking the time to answer. I appreciate it. I  understood what you two have explained, but are those two sentences mentioned grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Unlike for example "go bowling" we don't say "go cinema" but "go **to the** cinema".

Comment: I wouldn't use the simple past, but either the present or the present perfect sound okay to me.